# C# LINQ filtering lists

Tags: c#, linq

It's my first time using LINQ and I don't really get it yet.

I tried to understand it via an example but I need some help.

I created a class "Person":

```
class Person
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    private int age { get; set; }
    private bool parent { get; set; }
    private bool child { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age, bool parent, bool child)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

I created a list of "people":

```
people.Add(new Person("Joel", 12, false, true));
        people.Add(new Person("jana", 22, false, false));
        people.Add(new Person("Stefan", 45, true, false));
        people.Add(new Person("Kurt", 25, false, false));
        people.Add(new Person("Sebastian", 65, true, false));
        people.Add(new Person("George", 14, false, true));
        people.Add(new Person("Noel", 50, true, false));
```

Now I would like to get out every person which is set as a parent.
But I'm stuck here:

```
var parents = people.Where()
```

Comment: `var parents = people.Where(p => p.parent);` will return all results where `parent` property is `true` . 
In this case, `parent` is a `bool` type and you can evaluate it without `==` or `Equals`, but, for **non boolean** properties you should use the **equality** comparison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The linq statement should be

```
var parents = people.Where(x => x.parent);
```

and change `private bool parent { get; set; }` to `public bool parent { get; set; }`

Comment: Alright I think I fightet with it cause all the properties of the Person class are set to private. What if I would like to keep it like that? Is there also a solution for this? But thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Toast You could expose it as a read only property `public bool parent { get; private set; }`.  That way you can see if the person is a parent, but not mutate it.

Comment: @Mr.Toast no you need at least reading access to the property you want to filter

Answer (score 4):

```
var peopleWithParents = people.Where(x => x.parent == true).ToList();
```

Although it may take a little while to get your head around, the syntax is pretty simple, and becomes really comfortable to use. Keep in mind that 'where' acts as a filter, and 'select' acts as a projection. Remember that you will need the properties to be publicly visible. You can keep the setters private if you like. You could even introduce a method to check that the parent exists, and call it in the lambda.

Let's say hypothetically that your person class was more complex.

```
class Person
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public int age { get; private set; }
    public Person parent { get; private set; }
    public bool child { get; private set; }

    public bool HasParent()
    {
        return parent != null;
    }

    public Person(string name, int age, Person parent, bool child)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

You could do something like this to get a list of person objects representing all the parents:

```
var parents = people.Where(x => x.parent != null).Select(x => x.parent).ToList();
```

or

```
var parents = people.Where(x => x.HasParent()).Select(x => x.parent).ToList();
```

You also don't need to use 'x', and this letter is only in scope within each clause; could even order these parents by age:

```
var parents = people.Where(y => y.HasParent()).Select(z => z.parent).OrderBy(x => x.age).ToList();
```

Maybe you would like to get the oldest parent from the above collection:

```
var oldestParent = parents.OrderByDescending(x => x.age).FirstOrDefault();

if (oldestParent != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{oldestParent.name} is the oldest, at {oldestParent.age}");
}
```

You can combine multiple checks in your query:

```
var parentsOfPeopleWithChildren = people.Where(x => x.parent != null && x.child).Select(x => x.parent).ToList();
```

Also recall that in C# you generally Capitalise the first letter of properties. Eg:

```
public bool Child { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed description! Very helpful

Comment: No problem. I recall when I was first learning LINQ and Lambda, I struggled; what made it easier for me was using a Visual Studio add-on called ReSharper. It is quite popular in the industry, and although it can feel a little uncomfortable at first (to use), it will suggest better ways for you to write code, often taking advantage of LINQ, and generally make you a better developer. If you are a student, head to JetBrain's website, and get it free for a year, otherwise try the 30 day trial.

Comment: I'm already using it :) curious to see what it can do regarding LINQ and Lambda!

Comment: Write some foreach loops and see what it suggests. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `LINQ` is quite straight-forward:

```
var query = people.Where(x => x.parent);
```

However, your `parent` may not be accessible due to its *access modifier*.

If you don't want it to be changed from outside once declared (and that's likely the reason why you declare the properties by the constructor's parameters). I recommend you to use `public { get; private set; }`

```
class Person
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public int age { get; private set; }
    public bool parent { get; private set; }
    public bool child { get; private set; }

    public Person(string name, int age, bool parent, bool child)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```