# How to filter items with DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datatable, rowfilter

I  have `listbox` in my project which is bind to `datasource`. I would like to be able to filter items only to items matches text i type in additional `textbox` control. I knew that i might use following `DefaultView.RowFilter` property as shown below in my old *vb.net project*. Nevertheless when i try to do the same in  my most recent *visual studio C# project* seems like `DefaultView` is not anymore recognized. Any thoughts if this was decommised or any other way around how could i filter items?

```
listbox1.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Nummer] like '%" & lbSearchProd.Text.Trim()
```

**Edit For @dr.null**

I've added following line nevertheless i am getting the error below. Note that Datasource contains items.

```
(cbClient.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Value] like '%" + txtFilterClient.Text.Trim() + "%'";
```

[image]

This is how i bind the control:

```
public void LoadDataToClients(IEnumerable<IdValueReadModel> clients)
{
    cbClient.DataSource = clients.ToList();
    cbClient.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbClient.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

Data is there:

[image]

Comment: No `Option Strict Off` in c# to allow writing this code. Turning that option off in your old vb.net project was a mistake in the first place. In c# you must cast the `.DataSource` object to the assigned type. If it's a `DataTable` as your code snippet suggests then you need to write: `(listbox1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = ...`.

Comment: As suggested, you should have had `Option Strict On` in your VB app in the first place, then you would have done the right thing there and not had to do anything here. That said, you really ought to be using a `BindingSource` anyway, in C# and VB. Add a `BindingSource` to your form, bind the `DataTable` to that and that to the `ListBox`, then you can just set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: @dr.null i did and i see no error nevertheless when executed the code i am getting: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

(... as System.Data.DataTable) returned null.`
You can check my main post i've added screenshoot. Datasource contains items. What's the issue now?

Comment: What is the type of the data source? `DataTable` ? `DataView` ? else ? Did you bind the `.DataSource` before calling this code?

Comment: @dr.null yes i i bind control by calling `LoadDataToClients()` before i use ur code and there is data in control already - see main post i pasted the code.

Comment: Then it's not `DataTable` nor `DataView`. It's `List<IdValueReadModel>` and you can't handle it as other type. The `List<T>` has no `DataView` property. You need to filter the list using `Linq` query. Or better adopt John's suggestion by using a `BindingSource` instead.

Comment: @dr.null if i would convert List<IdValueReadModel> to Datatable would it work? Second question how could i use linq based on my code (example)?

Comment: Yes it'll work with `DataTable`. You can return one from your data layer instead of `List<T>`. As for Linq examples, too many around. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188523/c-sharp-linq-filtering-lists). Find some more. Again, try the `BindingSource` as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clarifying the comments to your question above.

First of all

```vb
listbox1.DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Nummer] like '%" & lbSearchProd.Text.Trim()
```

This line works in your old vb.net project because you have had the [`Option Strict Off`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) which [allows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#remarks) implicit narrowing conversions, late binding, and implicit typing that results in an `object` type. You should not allow the mentioned if you want to write good vb.net code and avoid possible mistakes and bugs by doing so. In c#, you don't have that option. You need to cast the `object` to the type of the assigned object instance to access it.

Second of all, your data source here is a `List<T>` not `DataTable`. They are two different things and you can't apply what can be written for one to another. You need `Linq` to filter a `List<T>`.

Some suggested solutions.

**DataTable**
Get a `DataTable` from your data access. Something like:

```cs
// SqlClient example...
private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("...."))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select...", con))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Bind it:

```cs
private void LoadClient()
{
    cbClient.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbClient.ValueMember = "Id";
    cbClient.DataSource = GetDataTable();
}
```

Handle the `TextBox.TextChanged` to filter or remove the filter:

```cs
private void txtFilterClient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbClient.DataSource is DataTable dt)
    {
        var str = txtFilterClient.Text.Trim();

        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            ? null
            : $"Value LIKE '%{str}%'";
    }
}
```

**BindingSource**
Like the first solution, get a `DataTable` but bind the control to the multipurpose [`BindingSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

```cs
private void LoadClient()
{
    cbClient.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbClient.ValueMember = "Id";
    cbClient.DataSource = new BindingSource(GetDataTable(), null);
}

private void txtFilterClient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbClient.DataSource is BindingSource bs)
    {
        var str = txtFilterClient.Text.Trim();

        bs.Filter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            ? null
            : $"Value LIKE '%{str}%'";
    }
}
```

**List<`T`>**
If you need to manipulate a `List<T>` and you have a model like:

```cs
public class IdValueReadModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can execute `Linq` queries to filter the data source which it's here of type `List<IdValueReadModel>`. You need to cache the original list in a class field to be the data source when you clear the filter. Run a `Linq` query to bind a **new** filtered list.

```cs
private List<IdValueReadModel> clientCache;

private void LoadClient()
{
    clientCache = // Get/assign the list...
    cbClient.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbClient.ValueMember = "Id";
    cbClient.DataSource = clientCache;
}

private void txtFilterClient_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var str = txtFilterClient.Text.Trim().ToLower();

    cbClient.DataSource = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
        ? clientCache
        : clientCache
        .Where(c => c.Value.ToLower().Contains(str))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: in your RowFilter if filter text is empty what exactly means that does this:  `? null` ?

Comment: It's [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to set or remove the filter if the search word is empty. Just like: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) //clear the filter else //set the filter;`. The [vb.net equivalent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator) is `.RowFilter = If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str), Nothing, $"Value LIKE '%{str}%'")`. You want to remove the filter if no word to search. Don't you?

Comment: but it doesn;t clean datasource itself right which means datasource stay as it is but if no matching words control's items will be shown empty list?

Comment: @Arie Correct. The source data remains as it was when you set/remove the filter.