# C# how to filter listed files on Data Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

my program has a datagridview where selected files are listed. Those files can be filtered with a searchbox. Here is my code:

```
private void durchsuchenButton(object sender, EventArgs e)//search button
    {
        string searchingText = textBox1.Text; 
       
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) == false) 
        {
            methode.dateiDurchsuchen(ref searchingText, dateienList);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
public void dateiDurchsuchen(ref string searchingText, BindingList<Datei> dateienList)
    {
        foreach (Datei datei in dateienList.ToList())
        {
            if (!datei.dateiname.ToLower().Contains(searchingText))
            {
                dateienList.Remove(datei);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is if so many documents are listed, like 1000, then the searching functions way too slow to filter. In addition, if there are too many filtered files to be listed, I get an error message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Row index provided is out of range.

So I tried the following code:

```
BindingList<Datei> neueDateienListe = new BindingList<Datei>(); //create new bindinglist
foreach(Datei datei in dateienList)
        {
            if(datei.dateiname.Contains(searchingText) == true)
            {
                neueDateienListe.Add(datei);
            }
        }
        dateienList = neueDateienListe;
        dateienList.ResetBindings();
```

didn't even filter and there was no response so I tried another:

```
string newSearchingText = searchingText;
BindingList<Datei> neueDateienListe = new BindingList<Datei>(dateienList.Where(x => x.dateiname.Contains(newSearchingText)).ToList());
        neueDateienListe = dateienList;
```

And same, the program does nothing with the code above. I am now stuck. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816389/14171304) examples to filter different types of data Sources. The third example is what you need to do here. However, I'd give the `BindingSource` example a go if I were you.

Comment: @dr.null Thanks for the comment. I guess it is the answer I had been looking for, but I did it in my way, which is probably less efficient :)