# How to get auto suggestions in combobox wherever the input value match dropdown list in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to filter the Combobox list items based on the input value in the same combobox wherever matches in list items.

I am trying in c# winforms, visual studio.

I am in learning the code, kindly help me.

```
ComboBoxDealer.DataSource = dt;
ComboBoxDealer.DisplayMember = "Dealer_Name";
ComboBoxDealer.ValueMember = "Id";
ComboBoxDealer.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
ComboBoxDealer.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Comment: See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816389/14171304) for example. The **DataTable** section. Replace `$"Value LIKE '%{str}%'"` with `$"Dealer_Name LIKE '%{str}%'"`.